# Pourquoi quand un homme se meurt, on dit qu'il « s'éteint », et quand il est mort, on l'appelle « feu » ?

Tags: origine-ou-raison, société

Simple coïncidence ou y a-t-il une origine bien définie ? Si je ne me trompe pas « feu » signifie « mort depuis peu de temps » mais pourquoi une restriction de temps et à partir de quand ne dit-on plus « feu » mais « défunt » ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Feu* (ou *feue* pour une femme) s'emploie pour une personne décédée *depuis peu*, sinon on use d'un synonyme tel que *mort, défunt, décédé* ou *trépassé* (utilisé surtout par les marins et dans leurs régions natales, ou, dans la littérature des morts-vivants).

*Feu*, *feue*, adjectif, du latin populaire *fatutus* : "qui a accompli son destin [ou *fatum*]"  – Le Robert

S'*éteindre*, est lié au symbole de la bougie (ou au cierge d'église).

Elle s'éteint lorsqu'elle n'a plus rien à consumer, qu'il n'y a plus d'énergie, ou avec le dernier souffle du mourant qui disperse ses ultimes forces.

Comment: Merci de ta réponse mais quand est-il de la durée séparant le moment où l'on peut dire "feu" et "défunt" ? Existe-t-il une règle établie ?

Comment: Lorsque la manifestation du deuil prend fin (elle dépend de la personne endeuillée) . Le deuil de veuve, le plus long de tous, dure deux ans selon *http://www.theatre-contemporain.net/textes/Les-regles-du-savoir-vivre-dans-la-societe-moderne-10/infos-texte/type/ensavoirplus/idcontent/2551* Toutefois, il s'agit là de rites de moins en moins observés par les laïcs. Ces mœurs sont très liées aux religions et à certaines positions sociales

Comment: Attention, « feu » s'accorde après le déterminant mais reste invariable avant : *Feu* la mère de Madame, la *feue* mère de Madame.

Answer (score 3):

*Feu* vient du latin *fatum* ce qui signifie « le destin ». Rien à voir avec les flammes.

N'étant utilisé plus que dans le langage écrit, il est communément remplacé par « défunt ».

À noter que l'accord au féminin est toléré (*Feue ma tante …*).